# using pre trained glove vectors

Tags: nlp, spacy

i am using python 2.7 64 bit and i want to use glove pre trained word vectors of
wikipedia corpus in spacy.By defaut spacy is trained on common crawl corpus of glove.can anyone provide code snippet for the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your vectors already trained in the standard word-tab-vector format, you can add it to a spaCy model using this example code from the [spaCy Github](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/vectors_fast_text.py):

```
with open(vectors_loc, 'rb') as file_:
    header = file_.readline()
    nr_row, nr_dim = header.split()
    nlp.vocab.reset_vectors(width=int(nr_dim))
    for line in file_:
        line = line.rstrip().decode('utf8')
        pieces = line.rsplit(' ', int(nr_dim))
        word = pieces[0]
        vector = numpy.asarray([float(v) for v in pieces[1:]], dtype='f')
        nlp.vocab.set_vector(word, vector)  # add the vectors to the vocab
```

What might be more efficient is to use the new [CLI](https://spacy.io/api/cli#vocab) API, which will let you create a new blank model with your custom vectors. Note that using different vectors will probably break all the other pipeline components (NER, POS, dependency) since they expect the existing vectors.